# Perl match with regex a number and as many following characters as the number specifies within a string

Tags: regex, perl, backreference

I (think I) am quite experienced in Perl, still I have a nasty question I'm trying to solve.
I have to match a string (whose format I cannot change coming out from a bioinformatic software) in this format:

```
[\+\-][0-9]+[ACGTacgt]+
```

Actually this would be easy, though the number of repeats of the pattern `[ACGTacgt]` is not quite 1 or more but the number defined by `[0-9]+` 
so it can be

```
[...whatever...]+2ac[...whatever...]
+4acta
+3atg
```

etc..

Now to test if the regex work I'm just playing with a substitution and I tried the following way:

```
$mystring =~ s/[\+\-]([0-9]+)[ACGTacgt]{\1}//g
```

Unfortunately this guy above does not work and I get an error complaining about unescaped braces. Indeed if I define a proper number instead of \1 the thing works:

```
$mystring =~ s/[\+\-]([0-9]+)[ACGTacgt]{1}//g
```

I need it to work since the format might contain sequences like `ac.,.+2caaa..a.c` from which I have to get exactly the `+2ca` leaving separately from the rest.

Is it possible in one step, or there's a logical reason which I'm missing right now for which it's not possible?

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

berutti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{$N}` component of the regex is a modifier, which can't use a backreference as its count. You could work around it with an embedded perl expression:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = 'ac.,.+2caaa..a.c';
$string =~ s/[+-]([0-9]+)(??{ "[ACGTacgt]{$1}" })//g;
print "$string\n";
```

Note that [embedded subexpressions](https://perldoc.pl/perlre#(??%7B-code-%7D)) are a last resort, and for obvious reasons prevent the regex from being optimized properly - it is IMO an appropriate tradeoff for this exact case where the matched substring must be removed, but if your requirements are slightly different, a split-out iterative approach may be more appropriate.

Comment: I think you should mention good-practice-standing of constructs like `??{..}`

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the usage here. The only thing to mention would be that it would not be the most performant solution, but I am not sure any other solution would do better, depending on the requirements.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47866787/4653379) for instance (and another above it, commenting on it). It's not "wrong" it's just tricky and error-prone.  And some uses are disallowed. Etc.

Comment: I agree it's not ideal to have to resort to subexpressions, but depending on the requirements, the tradeoff is worth it in this case IMO.

Comment: Of course, it's a trade-off (there's always some of that!), all I am saying is that I think it should be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: First of all thank you! I think this is the solution I need. Efficiency is at this point not extremely important. Should it become I think then it's worth to dig into the source code of the software producing the output (even if that wouldn't be appreciated to change a very standard software in a production environment, that's why I wanted to avoid it)

I'm realising I have a lot to learn about perl regex still! Is there any ambiguity or problem using such a subexpression here (aside from performance)?

Comment: Forget the question, I followed the link and found the WARNING message quite useful, so the functionality of this syntax might not survive an update of perl :)

Comment: @berutti No, the functionality is guaranteed. What might change is the performance optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Can iterate over numbers and in the loop body match captured-number of letters that follow

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $s = q(ac.,.+2caaa..a.c-3acgg+1tt);

while ($s =~ /[+-]([0-9]+)/g) { 
    my $c = $1; 
    $s =~ /\G([acgt]{$c})/i or next;

    say "$c$1";  # or process it further / store it ...
}
```

The `\G` assertion makes its regex start from where the previous `m//g` match ended, as needed.  This is a standard approach to "*chain global matches*" and generally scan text by coordinating multiple regex. See docs for it in [Assertions in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) and, for far more detail, [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) (search for `\G`).

Prints

```
2ca
3acg
1t
```

If the `[+-]` need be extracted as well, add capturing parens around it and renumerate captures (that'll be `$1` and the number in `$2`)

Please clarify other requirements -- for instance: Do you only need to extract the patterns or should anything in particular happen with the original string as well?

---

**Update**  It's clarified that the matches also need be removed from the string.

An easy way is to simply remove them with another regex, after they have been collected.

After the same processing as above, the collected matches are used to form a pattern with alternation for their removal. This is also efficient since by construction the subpatterns in the alternation come in the order of their appearance in the string

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $string = q(ac.,.+2caaa..a.c-3acgg+1tt);

my @matches;

while ($string =~ /([+-])([0-9]+)/g) { 
    my ($sign, $count)  = ($1, $2);
    $string =~ /\G([acgt]{$count})/i or next;    
    push @matches, $sign.$count.$1; 
}    
say for @matches;

my $matches_re = '(?:' . join('|', map { quotemeta } @matches) . ')';

$string =~ s/$matches_re//g;    
say $string;
```

where i've now joined the sign `[+-]` to the match.

It prints

```
+2ca
-3acg
+1t
ac.,.aa..a.cgt
```

Comment: I tried to write a solution along these lines but it becomes extremely complicated if removing the string is a requirement as in the OP. You should also check whether the second regex succeeds, in case there are instances that don't have sufficient following letters.

Comment: @Grinnz Well, yeah, good points but we omitted all error checking (your solution as well).  I'd expect them to add that.  Here at least it's easy to add any and all checks.

Comment: @Grinnz "_removing the string is a requirement_"  --  I didn't see it that way, on the contrary, I think they need to extract the pattern (and never mind the original string).  It says (my emphasis) "_**to test** if the regex work I'm just playing with a substitution..._" ...

Comment: The original code does not extract the string - the exact requirement is unclear, hence why I said "if" it's a requirement.

Comment: There is no error checking required in my solution, as any parts of the string that do not match the whole expression will not be affected.

Comment: Sorry actually I think I should have been clearer here, In principle it's also helpful, but the above solution serves better. 
So the full requirement would be to extract the matches, but also get the string cleaned by the matches, because they have to go thru two different processings! 
I think the representation of the string (which are genomic variants at a position) is not the most efficient ever... but I can't change it

Comment: @berutti Alright.  For your information, i've added code to remove matches from the original string.